# Trojans detected in ldb bitcoin database?

Tags: leveldb

I started regular scan and clamscan found lots of trojans in bitcon.lfb blocks.

What is it? A mistake?

```
sudo clamscan --infected --recursive --exclude-dir="^/sys" /

/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/592744.ldb: Win.Trojan.Jerusalem-47 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/589268.ldb: Win.Trojan.Nomenclatura-1 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/644616.ldb: Win.Trojan.Redx-1 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/638596.ldb: Win.Trojan.Phantom-5 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/649206.ldb: Win.Trojan.Trojan-251 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/335390.ldb: Win.Trojan.Zherkov-8 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/589273.ldb: Win.Trojan.B-67 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/647056.ldb: Win.Trojan.EDV-3 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/333900.ldb: Win.Trojan.AIDS-1 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/590327.ldb: Win.Trojan.Syslock-2 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/641108.ldb: Win.Trojan.Jerusalem-15 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/336793.ldb: Win.Trojan.CIA-1 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/590264.ldb: Win.Trojan.Yankee-16 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/647796.ldb: Win.Trojan.Vienna-43 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/638638.ldb: Win.Trojan.Tori-1 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/642244.ldb: Win.Trojan.Ping-2 FOUND
/root/.bitcoin/data/blocks/index/649309.ldb: Win.Trojan.Copyright-2 FOUND
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's vandalism. Some virus signatures were uploaded to the blockchain as a prank: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/25otbt/someone_put_a_virus_signature_in_the_bitcoin/

It seems those are some of that cases.